# Insist on number of rows on left side of join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where I want to join two tables where there is 1 record on the left and many on the right side but only need information from the right that exists in all of those records - in other words, insist on only getting 1:1 not 1:n in my results.

Example, if I run this statement below, I get 2 records for the WHERE statement:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) bi.*
FROM [DB4_Default].[dbo].[t_LinkBreakInfo] AS bi
WHERE bi.LinkID = 58150701
```

When I include a join to a table which contains more info than returned from the query above, it finds 7 records on the right hand side. So, the results of the statement below results in 2 x 7 = 14 rows.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) bi.*, nav.security_name
FROM [DB4_Default].[dbo].[t_LinkBreakInfo] AS bi
  JOIN [DB4_Default].[dbo].[Positions] AS nav
    ON bi.LinkID = nav.link_identifier
WHERE bi.LinkID = 58150701 
  AND nav.data_origin_type = 'Local'
```

I still want just 2 records as per the first statement example but with the addition of the column value from the join.

Any ideas?

Comment: G your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You select two `bi` rows. To each `bi` row there can belong seveleral `nav` rows. Which of its `nav.security_name` do you want to show for a `bi` row? The first in the alphabet? The last? The longest? ...

Comment: What is the `TOP (1000)` for?

Comment: a) where linkID matches, the security name in the right table is the same irrespective of how many rows so, the first, last or middle is fine. b) I left top 1000 in from original select run just for now, it isn't needed, thanks

Comment: If the name is supposed to be always the same, then you seem to have a problem with your database design; the name should reside in the bi table, not in the nav table then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want just any security_name for a bi row, no matter which. Let's take the minimum (first in the alphabet). The most simple way is to select it in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
  bi.*, 
  (
    SELECT MIN(nav.security_name)
    FROM db4_default.dbo.positions AS nav
    WHERE nav.link_identifier = bi.linkid
    AND nav.data_origin_type = 'Local'
  ) AS secname
FROM db4_default.dbo.t_linkbreakinfo bi
WHERE bi.linkid = 58150701;
```

Alternatively in the `FROM`clause:

```
SELECT bi.*, nav.secname
FROM db4_default.dbo.t_linkbreakinfo bi
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT link_identifier, MIN(security_name) AS secname
  FROM db4_default.dbo.positions
  WHERE data_origin_type = 'Local'
  GROUP BY link_identifier
) nav ON nav.link_identifier = bi.linkid
WHERE bi.linkid = 58150701;
```

Comment: Thanks for this version, I had success with both versions, fixed a previous error on second one. Both worked up until me taking away the final WHERE Statement which resulted in secname = NULL on everything and the executing query continuing for some time after.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the second query, which I immediately fixed (I had `MIN(nav.security_name)` instead of `MIN(security_name)`). Both queries show the bi rows plus a name if one exists. If you only want to show bi rows for which exists a name then you cannot use the first query, but must use the second and replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`)  there.

Comment: Recommended index: `create index idx on db4_default.dbo.positions(link_identifier, data_origin_type, security_name);`.

Comment: yes, I copied it prior to your edit. I also tried something out (WHERE secname IS NOT NULL) and I now see why there was a problem :) different record sets - thanks

Comment: Anyway, as mentioned in the comments under your request: It seems `security_name` belongs in the bi table. Place it there and your query becomes a mere `select * from db4_default.dbo.t_linkbreakinfo` :-)

Comment: I agree with you - it should, unfortunately, it's not my database and I'm only creating reporting views for analytics purposes and don't have permission to change how this application was designed - there's a lot of weird backwards things going on in this DB - thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join, which in SQL Server uses the `APPLY` keyword:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) bi.*, nav.security_name
FROM [DB4_Default].[dbo].[t_LinkBreakInfo] bi CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) nav.*
      FROM [DB4_Default].[dbo].[Positions] nav
      WHERE bi.LinkID = nav.link_identifier AND
            nav.data_origin_type = 'Local'
      ORDER BY nav.position_date
     ) nav
WHERE bi.LinkID = 58150701 ;
```

Normally, the subquery would have an `ORDER BY`, I added one pased on your comment.

For performance for the subquery, you want an index on `Positions(LinkId, data_origin_type, position_date)`.

Comment: I tried adding in an order by but it doesn't seem to work. I added it after 'Local' as ORDER BY nav.position_date. Have I done something wrong there?

Comment: also, when I take out the WHERE statement at the end, it has taken more than 8 minutes to execute the query with no end in sight :(

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the update. Still working out how to apply the INDEX so I can run it without a where statement :)